# How to programmatically paste a string into a browser input area?

Tags: qt

İ can copy a string with clipboard (like Ctrl+c) but i can’t paste where mouse focused..

When I copied data, I want to paste string to input area where I have already focused with clicked on browser. Just like if the user had pressed Ctrl+v.

I want to paste to chrome  or mozzila browser input area (outside of my app.).. my os is windows..

```
QClipboard *clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
QString originalText = clipboard->text();//mevcut hafız
clipboard->setText(subString); //hafıza degistir
qDebug () << "Hafız : " << originalText;
```

Comment: What is your OS? Do you paste on the window of the same application or other's?

Comment: Is the focus where you want to paste within your application our outside of it?

Comment: my apllication in windows.. And i want to paste to chrome input area.. YEs outside of my aplication..

Comment: This can only be done by sending windows messages to the Chrome process. It needs to be done using native API, there's no Qt functionality for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

If you have control over the O/S and browser installed on the computer in question, you will have to control that through the mechanisms provided by that OS and browser directly. This is not something Qt can do for you, it will rely on native APIs.

OTOH if you are planning for this to be more general purpose, you are looking at **a rather hairy hack** that consists of emulating mouse clicks and keyboard input. For this my suggestion is then to use something like the [QtTestLib](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtest-overview.html). I am not sure how "mebeddable" this is, however you could look at it's sources to learn how it goes about moving the mouse and simulating keyboard input and clicks etc.

The approach would then be to enumerate open windows by title, filter on known/supported browser names and versions, then proceed to focus that window and feed it the necessary stream of keyboard shortcuts to give focus to the address bar and stream characters from the clipboard as keyboard events.

I have not done this with [QtTestLib](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtest-overview.html). My experience is with [Java Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html), which is quite awesome for tasks.

Good luck!